# Extremely slow copy on veracrypt encrypted drive

Tags: backup, veracrypt, cross-platform

I have been trying to come up with a good solution for encrypted backups that I can access cross-platform. I decided to encrypt a partition on a 4TB external with VeraCrypt—AES, no PIM—and then format the partition with exFAT.

I copied a bunch of data from my Mac and it seemed to be pretty quick (about 80MB/s instead of 120MB/s). I left it overnight so I don't know if there was a slowdown.

On Linux (Arch) however, I left an rsync job running over the weekend on 100GB of data and it just never finished. No matter how many times I run it it just gets stuck, on a different file every time. I tried just using the file manager to copy data, and it is working better, but I get periodic slowdowns where the write speed drops to around 500 KB/s or maybe 1.5MB/s.

The speed increases and decreases, but as more time passes, the speed tends to be closer to the 500KB/s more often than not.

Is there any reason for this insanely low performance? Is there anything I can do to avoid it? I could potentially try using ext4 or something, but I can't use any other encryption solution because then I can't read the data on another platform.

Comment: I actually think I am going to be forced to cancel the backup and reformat. The speed has now dropped to 5 KB/s, with an estimated 700 hours remaining. It got through 90GB of data in about 20 minutes, and then just got stuck. Really strange behavior.

Comment: Is AESNI built into your kernel? If not it may be using software for AES encryption rather then farming it off to the acceleration in your CPU. That said, I would have expected more  performance from a typical software implementation.

Comment: Yeah, it is. I also just tried the standard LUKS encryption with a different external (I believe that uses AES too), no performance impact there. It's strange too, because the first ~90GB of transfer was pretty fast.